# KivyMD with MYSQL : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, kivy, urllib

Yesterday I used my app and everything was ok. I didn't change anything while yesterday and today but now I get this error :

```
[ERROR  ] [Loader      ] Failed to load image <https://lereseaufoncier.fr/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/image-03-09-21-02-43-2-scaled.jpeg>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1279, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1325, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1274, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1034, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 1448, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program     Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant
```

I get this error for all my images blog posts... (or maybe 15/20 images)...

I'm using kivyMD and pymysql for connect to my database. But everything works yesterday with the same exactly code since more than three weeks.

Should I install some depencies ?

Here a pip freeze :

```
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.7
docutils==0.18
idna==3.3
Kivy==2.0.0
kivy-deps.angle==0.3.0
kivy-deps.glew==0.3.0
kivy-deps.gstreamer==0.3.2
kivy-deps.sdl2==0.3.1
Kivy-Garden==0.1.4
kivymd @ file:///C:/kivyLRF/KivyMD
Pillow==8.4.0
Pygments==2.10.0
PyMySQL==1.0.2
pypiwin32==223
pywin32==302
requests==2.26.0
urllib3==1.26.7
```

and here the module I import in my py files :

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.list.list import ImageLeftWidget
import config
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch, OneLineAvatarIconListItem, ThreeLineAvatarListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import functions
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
#Window.fullscreen = True
```

and here my config file (but I know there is no problem here...):
import pymysql.cursors

```
connexion = pymysql.connect(host='DATABASE ON OVH',
                         user='my user',
                         password='my password',                             
                         db='lrf',
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         port=my port,
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
print ("connect successful!!")
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know what, how or why, but the problem is gone.. Two hours later, it was ok, it works again...